# Wagtail, how to test PageChooserBlock returns correctly typed page?

Tags: django, wagtail

so at my company we've recently ran into a problem. We have a custom StructBlock, containing as it's first attribute a PageChooserBlock.

```
page = blocks.PageChooserBlock(required=False)
```

In the StructBlock we then call render():

```
def render(self, value, context=None):
    target_page = value['page'].basepage or context.get('page')
    if target_page is not None:
        context = context or {}
        context['new_value'] = target_page.CUSTOM_METHOD_DEFINED_IN_BASEPAGE()
    return super(CustomStructBlock, self).render(value, context)
```

Now the problem was, that the type of value['page'] was not the actual page chosen, but a related object from the wagtailcore page model. 
This one didn't have our custom method, and after figuring out that we can add ".basepage" to get our original page back, 
we now want to test that this will keep working.

Any help on how to test this would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `BasePage` is a page model defined somewhere in your project? The standard way of getting from a wagtailcore `Page` instance to the correctly-typed page object is `page.specific`, but `page.basepage` will also work if you know your page is an instance of BasePage.

As of Wagtail 1.8, PageChooserBlock supports a `target_model` parameter:

```
page = blocks.PageChooserBlock(required=False, target_model=BasePage)
```

This limits the page chooser so that you can only choose pages that are instances of `BasePage` (or a subclass), and also ensures that the page is returned as a `BasePage` instance rather than just a wagtailcore `Page`.